# Struggling to deserialize a JSON string using Newtonsoft.JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm struggling to deserialize a JSON string to an object in C#.

The string in question is

```
{"Hallway":2,"Hot Water":7,"Kitchen":4,"Landing":6,"Living Room":3,"Office":1,"Utility":5}
```

My current code is:

```
dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(outputData);

Dictionary<string,int> Zones = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (dynamic Temp in response)
{
    Zones.Add(Temp.Name, 1);
}
```

`outputData` is the raw JSON string above and comes from an IoT device.

The code above works such that I get the names into the dictionary object but I'd like to capture the number as well i.e. replace the 1 with the correct number.

I've tried `Temp.Value` and `Temp.First.Value` which errors with:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Add(string, int)' has some invalid arguments'

Comment: what is wrong with `var Zones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,int>>(outputData);` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need for the loop or `dynamic` at all, you can deserialise directly to a dictionary:

```
var Zones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(json);
```

PS Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies...

Comment: There's lots of people using dynamic when they shouldn't, it's felinicide on a grand scale.

Comment: Sorry about the kittens, this code is a number of edits from the original with me trying to break out each step and work out what was going wrong, variable names and types all want tidying up yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can deserialize to a `Dictionary<string,int>` directly :

```
var dict=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,int>>(json);
```

Comment: Very similar to DavidG's answer, thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
Zones.Add(Temp.Name, 1);
```

you need

```
Zones.Add(Temp.Name, (int) Temp.Value);
```

Comment: This also works but as pointed out DavidG I can ditch the loop entirely.  I had never thought about casting the number to int as the debug output looked like it had done this i.e. {"Hallway":2}.

Comment: Yep, don't use dynamic where possible. If you look in the debugger it'll tell you what type it is, even if it looks like an int, it's not always an int!

Comment: This code is part of a larger project and I have been using properly defined classes and variables elsewhere but this bit was annoying me.